# Azure mongodb $in query not working

Tags: java, mongodb, azure, grails, azure-cosmosdb

I have employee collection with 140 documents

```
{

    "name" : "name1",

    "dept" : "tech",

    "address" : "adr3"

}
```

In all 140 documents dept is tech
When I execute the query in **azure mongodb**

```
    MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("test")
    def query = new BasicDBObject(['dept':['$in':['tech']]])
    FindIterable documents = db.getCollection("employees").find(query)
    def outList =  documents.collect {it}
```

I get only 101 documents instead of 140 records

This works fine in **local mongodb**. Till last week this was working in azure for me.
Am I doing something wrong here ? Anyone facing similar situation ?

If I change query to

```
def query = new BasicDBObject(['dept':'tech'])
```

I get all 140 documents

If I change batch size to 10, $in query returns only 10 documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xal. According to the sharing in this case : [Cosmos Mongo API "In" Array expression issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770028/cosmos-mongo-api-in-array-expression-issue?noredirect=1#comment86643702_49770028) ,it seems that the issue on Microsoft side.You could wait until the bug fixed.

The reply as below:

> Thank you David for reporting this! I investigated the issue, it’s a
>   bug on our side manifesting under a combination of conditions. I
>   already have made a fix for it and will check it in by end of week
>   (then it’s up to our deployment cycle to propagate the fix to all
>   datacenters around the world). Let me know if you have queries that
>   don’t work and are blocking you. Best regards, Orestis

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks David and Jay

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i sorted it out by using **`$elemMatch`**

```
mongoDB.collection('mycol', (err, collection) => {            
    if (err) throw err;            
    collection.find({dept: {$elemMatch:{$in : ['tech']}}}).toArray((err, docs) => {
        console.log(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, Is it working for you, not for me as dept is not an array.