# Cosmos Mongo API "In" Array expression issue

Tags: azure, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb

Are there issues with the IN expression?
We are having issues where it doesn't find the results we are asking for even though it exists?

{ "SerialNumber": "V8073023", "_t": "DeviceEventDataEvent", "EventType": NumberInt(4), "isDeleted": { $in: [false,null] }, "EventNumber": 122 }
Returns the document correctly, however when using IN

{ "SerialNumber": "V8073023", "_t": "DeviceEventDataEvent", "EventType": NumberInt(4), "isDeleted": { $in: [false,null] }, "EventNumber": { $in: [122] } }
No data is returned.

Comment: It seems works fine on my side.

Comment: David, you could post more details such as your sample document, db location.

Comment: Any updates now?

Comment: Hey @JayGong, thanks for looking into this. See my answer below. Its an issue on Microsofts side. Waiting for fix to be rolled out

Comment: @David HI, thanks for your sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft got back to me, issue their side. Thanks to everyone involved for still assisting.

> Thank you David for reporting this! 
>    I investigated the issue, it’s a bug on our side manifesting under a combination of conditions. I already have made a fix for it and will check it in by end of week (then it’s up to our deployment cycle to propagate the fix to all datacenters around the world).
>   Let me know if you have queries that don’t work and are blocking you.
>   Best regards,
>   Orestis

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce your issue on my side but failed. Please refer to my details.

My sample documents in my cosmos db:

```
{
        "id" : "1",
        "CustomerId" : 1,
        "Orders" : [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ]
},
{
        "id" : "2",
        "CustomerId" : 2,
        "Orders" : [
            "e",
            "f",
            "g"
        ]
}
```

Query 1：

[image]

Query 2:

[image]

My db was built in the region `East Asia`.If you have any difference with me, you could edit it.