# Can't iterate entire pymongo cursor when using $in query

Tags: mongodb, azure, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to iterate a result set returned by CosmosDB's MongoDB API. I'm using pymongo to connect to the database.

The query looks something like:

```
items = item_collection.find(filter={'store_id': 151, 'dept_id': {'$in': [17, 19]}})
```

However, I am only able to iterate through `101` items before the cursor is empty. Calling `items.count()` reveals there are definitely more results in the result set:

```
tally = 0

for item in items:
    tally += 1

print('Cursor total: %s --- Tally: %s' % (items.count(), tally))

# prints 'Cursor total: 627 --- Tally: 101'
```

Perhaps not a co-incidence, `101` is the default size of the first batch returned by a Mongo query.

Now, if I remove the `$in` part of the query, and issue something like:

```
item_collection.find(filter={'store_id': 151, 'dept_id': 17})
```

then `tally` and `items.count()` yield the same number.

Any insight into why this is happening would be welcomed!

Comment: Hi, any updates ?

Comment: @JayGong Not yet. I'll post here when I hear something.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar situations to you, according to the sharing in this case: [Cosmos Mongo API "In" Array expression issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770028/cosmos-mongo-api-in-array-expression-issue?noredirect=1#comment86643702_49770028) ,it seems that the issue of $in is on Microsoft side.You could wait until the bug fixed.

The ms feedback as below:

> Thank you David for reporting this! I investigated the issue, it’s a
>   bug on our side manifesting under a combination of conditions. I
>   already have made a fix for it and will check it in by end of week
>   (then it’s up to our deployment cycle to propagate the fix to all
>   datacenters around the world). Let me know if you have queries that
>   don’t work and are blocking you. Best regards, Orestis

Hope it helps you.